# What is the easiest way to save settings in VB.net

Tags: windows, vb.net, combobox, settings

I am creating a program which launches a game server. I have combobox in which the user can enter the ip, map, etc, of the game. How can I save what they have entered so that the next time they are already there so they don't have to re-enter them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Visual Studio's Settings Designer, Right click on your project then properties, navigate to the settings section, from there, you can add anything you want.
then you can access your settings from code like so

```
My.Settings.nameOfSettingsEntry = value
My.Settings.Save()
```

you'll find more details and screenshots [here](http://visualbasic.about.com/od/usingvbnet/a/appsettings.htm),

Comment: Thanks! I am slowly learning :) ... Just need to find time for programming with school :(

Answer (score 2):

You can also bind the settings to the control using the Properties Window.

Right click your project in the Solution Explorer and choose Properties. Go to Settings and create a new String setting. Then click on your ComboBox and open up the Application Settings > PropertyBinding section from the Properties Window. From there you can bind the control's text property to the String setting you just created.